# Trouble with operator << in class StringSet

Tags: c++, class, vector, set, operator-overloading

I am defining my own string class called `StringSet` using a vector of strings. I am assigned to overload the `>>`, `<<`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `+`, `+=` and `*` operators, and ran into a problem with `<<`. The output should be:

```
Welcome to stringset

hi everyone

"all" does not exist in the set.

hi
```

But it seems to be skipping the second and third lines. I am very new to overloading operators, so I am probably overlooking an obvious mistake.

header and class declaration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class StringSet
{
public:
    //Constructor
    StringSet();

    //Copy Constructor
    StringSet(const StringSet& s);

    //Default constructors
    StringSet(string initialStrings[], const int ARRAYSIZE);

    //Destructor
    ~StringSet();

    void add(const string s);
    void remove(const string s);

    //Returns length
    int size()
    {
       return length;
    }

    // Overload the << operator so that it outputs the strings
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const StringSet& s);

private:
    //size of the vector
    int length;
    // Vector to store strings
    vector <string> data;
};
```

function definitions:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outs, const StringSet& s) 
{
    outs << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        outs << s.data[i] << " ";
    }
    outs << "\n";
    return outs;
}

//Add a string to the vector
void StringSet::add(const string s)
{
    bool c = check(s);
    if (c == false)
    {
        data.push_back(s);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\"" << s << "\" already exists in the set.";
    }
}

// Remove a string from the vector 
void StringSet::remove(const string s)
{
    bool c = check(s);
    if (c == true)
    {
        vector<string>::iterator position = search(s);
        data.erase(position);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\"" << s << "\" does not exist in the set\n";
    }
}

StringSet::StringSet()
{
    length = 0;
}

StringSet::StringSet(string initialStrings[], const int ARRAYSIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        initialStrings[i] = " ";
    }
}

// Copy constructor
StringSet::StringSet(const StringSet& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i] = s.data[i];
    }
}

StringSet::StringSet()
{
    length = 0;
}

StringSet::StringSet(string initialStrings[], const int ARRAYSIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        initialStrings[i] = " ";
    }
}

// Copy constructor
StringSet::StringSet(const StringSet& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i] = s.data[i];
    }
}

// Check if a string exists in the vector
bool StringSet::check(const string s)
{
    vector<string>::iterator it = find(data.begin(), data.end(), s);
    if (it != data.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    ofstream outs;
    ifstream ins;
    StringSet doc1, doc2, query

    cout << "Welcome to stringset\n";
    doc1.add("hi");
    doc1.add("everyone");
    outs << doc1;
    doc1.remove("everyone");
    doc1.remove("all");
    outs << doc1;
}
```

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: We would at least need to see what `add` and `remove` do.

Comment: @john I have added `add`  and `remove` back in. thank you.

Comment: Now we need to see `check` and your constructor. PLEASE read [example]. Actually read it. You'll spend less time reading that, editing your question, and getting an answer here, than it will take you to keep responding to our repeated attempts at clarity - in the mean-time accumulating downvotes.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. please if someone finds a silly mistake in my code regarding the operator <<, please point it out. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a variable that stores the size of the set, you should increment/decrement it when adding/removing elements. You can also change the definition of the `StringSet::size()`:

```
int size() const
{
    return static_cast<int>(data.size());
}
```